# How to delete specific contact from phonebook

Tags: android

```
 Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone));
    Cursor cur = ctx.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                if (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME)).equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
                    ctx.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
                }
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    } finally {
        cur.close();
    }
```

Comment: What is your error or what is wrong, do you have log messages, crashes or something? What OS are you running ?

Comment: cursor doesn't return any record..but contact still exist..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following method:

```
private static final Uri CONTACT_CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;    

public static boolean deleteContact(final Context context, final String contactId) {
    if (null != context) {
        final Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(CONTACT_CONTENT_URI, contactId);
        final ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        try {
            final int deletedRowCount = contentResolver.delete(uri, null, null);
            return deletedRowCount > 0;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what is contact id

Comment: Each contact has a unique ID within phonebook database, you can retrieve that ID the same way you retrieve contact display name etc.

Comment: thnks..its done..